# Rebus MVC subscriber on remote machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, publish-subscribe, rebus

I've got a rebus server process running on one machine and an MVC website on another. I configure the message routing in the MVC website with a local input and error queue and the destination pointing to the queue myinputqueue@BusServer and when it runs it sends the subscription message without error but nothing seems to appear on the destination queue. The receiving bus never acknowledges it or creates a subscription entry.

It's using msmq as the transport and all queues have full permissions to the Everyone group.

I'm assuming I've not configured something correctly so I hope this is the right forum to raise the question.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though Everyone has access to the queues, and that sounds like there's nothing in the way of communicating freely, I'm not sure that it works that way.

In any case, I suggest you make sure your IIS app pool is runnig with some dedicated service user identity, which you can also use as the user account under which your server process is running.

With MSMQ, messages are never lost - so in your case, the subscription message is most likely sitting in an outgoing queue on the web server machine, or it might have been moved to the "Transactional dead-letter queue" which is where MSMQ ends up moving stuff that it cannot find a place for.

Could you try and take a look at the outgoing MSMQ queues and/or the transactional dead-letter queue to see if it's a user rights problem that is haunting you?

Comment: Thanks for the answer (and apologies for asking it on gitHub originally). The MVC app was running under ApplicationPoolIdentity so I'll experiment with a custom account. There are no messages however sat in the MVC input queue or the transaction dead letter queue and the latter even has a red cross against it. Does that mean it's disabled?

Comment: Mogens, you're a saviour. After subsequent attempts I did find entries in the transactional dead letter queue with the message Access Denied. After switching the app pool to use Network Service and granting the MachineName$ account on each machine write access to the queues in question messages have started to flow as expected. Thanks once again.